# How to save GPU memory usage in PyTorch

Tags: out-of-memory, pytorch

In PyTorch I wrote a very simple CNN discriminator and trained it. Now I need to deploy it to make predictions. But the target machine has a small GPU memory and got out of memory error. So I think that I can set `requires_grad = False` to prevent PyTorch from storing the gradient values. However I didn't find it making any difference.

There are about 5 millions of parameters in my model. But when predicting a single batch of input, it consumes about 1.2GB of memory. I think there should be no need for such large memory.

The question is how to save GPU memory usage when I just want to use my model to make predictions?

---

Here is a demo, I use `discriminator.requires_grad_` to disable/enable autograd of all parameters. But it seems to be no use.

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as functional

from pynvml.smi import nvidia_smi
nvsmi = nvidia_smi.getInstance()

def getMemoryUsage():
    usage = nvsmi.DeviceQuery("memory.used")["gpu"][0]["fb_memory_usage"]
    return "%d %s" % (usage["used"], usage["unit"])

print("Before GPU Memory: %s" % getMemoryUsage())

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # trainable layers
        # input: 2x256x256
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(2, 8, 5, padding=2) # 8x256x256
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2) # 8x128x128
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(8, 32, 5, padding=2) # 32x128x128
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2) # 32x64x64
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 96, 5, padding=2) # 96x64x64
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(4) # 96x16x16
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(96, 256, 5, padding=2) # 256x16x16
        self.pool4 = nn.MaxPool2d(4) # 256x4x4
        self.num_flat_features = 4096
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4096, 1024)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 256)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 1)
        # loss function
        self.loss = nn.MSELoss()
        # other properties
        self.requires_grad = True
    def forward(self, x):
        y = x
        y = self.conv1(y)
        y = self.pool1(y)
        y = functional.relu(y)
        y = self.conv2(y)
        y = self.pool2(y)
        y = functional.relu(y)
        y = self.conv3(y)
        y = self.pool3(y)
        y = functional.relu(y)
        y = self.conv4(y)
        y = self.pool4(y)
        y = functional.relu(y)
        y = y.view((-1,self.num_flat_features))
        y = self.fc1(y)
        y = functional.relu(y)
        y = self.fc2(y)
        y = functional.relu(y)
        y = self.fc3(y)
        y = torch.sigmoid(y)
        return y
    def predict(self, x, score_th=0.5):
        if len(x.shape) == 3:
            singlebatch = True
            x = x.view([1]+list(x.shape))
        else:
            singlebatch = False
        y = self.forward(x)
        label = (y > float(score_th))
        if singlebatch:
            y = y.view(list(y.shape)[1:])
        return label, y
    def requires_grad_(self, requires_grad=True):
        for parameter in self.parameters():
            parameter.requires_grad_(requires_grad)
        self.requires_grad = requires_grad


x = torch.cuda.FloatTensor(np.zeros([2, 256, 256]))
discriminator = Discriminator()
discriminator.to("cuda:0")

# comment/uncomment this line to make difference
discriminator.requires_grad_(False)

discriminator.predict(x)

print("Requires grad", discriminator.requires_grad)
print("After GPU Memory: %s" % getMemoryUsage())
```

By comment out the line `discriminator.requires_grad_(False)`, I got output:

```
Before GPU Memory: 6350MiB
Requires grad True
After GPU Memory: 7547MiB
```

While by uncomment the line, I got:

```
Before GPU Memory: 6350MiB
Requires grad False
After GPU Memory: 7543MiB
```

Comment: When I ran your code, the 'before' and 'after' GPU memory usage are both around 900MB. Why is your memory usage so high?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [pynvml](https://pypi.org/project/pynvml/).

This python tool made Nvidia so you can Python query like this:

```
from pynvml.smi import nvidia_smi
nvsmi = nvidia_smi.getInstance()
nvsmi.DeviceQuery('memory.free, memory.total')
```

You can always also execute:

```
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

To empty the cache and you will find even more free memory that way.

Before calling `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` if you have objects you don't use anymore you can call this:

```
obj = None
```

And after that you call

```
gc.collect()
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. `pynvml` is really awesome! However, I don't think `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` can solve my problem. Of course, recycling after prediction computation will decrease the memory usage at the end. But the peak memory usage won't decrease. And that's the bottleneck in my problem.

Comment: Once you get free memory you can ask adjust the batch size based on that.  Currently, you haven't set that. Just you set your image has 2 channels. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `model.eval()` with `torch.no_grad()` on your target machine when making predictions. `model.eval()` will switch model layers to eval mode. `torch.no_grad()` will deactivate autograd engine and as a result memory usage will be reduced.

```py
x = torch.cuda.FloatTensor(np.zeros([2, 256, 256]))
discriminator = Discriminator()
discriminator.to("cuda:0")

discriminator.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    discriminator.predict(x)
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems not to make difference. To my knowledge, `model.eval` just make differences for specific modules, such as `batchnorm` or `dropout`. It tells them to behave as in evaluating mode instead of training mode. But the doc didn't mention that it will tell variables not to keep gradients or some other datas. Besides, I am confused about how does torch know that my submodules should be in evaluation mode as I just call `eval` on my module. As for `requires_grad_` I have to implement this function for my module by my self and set all the submodules' `requires_grad` as `False`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not relevant anymore for your specific problem, but you could take a look at [Torchscript](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/Intro_to_TorchScript_tutorial.html)
It's a good way to decrease the size and complexity of your model. It also speeds up the prediction. Unfortunately it cant help with the training itself. It is just in general a good idea for deployment of pytorch models used in other hardware or embedded in c++ code for efficiency.
Cheers. :-)